# Adding a new language-locale in Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 170407)

Tags: sitecore

I need to add new languages in Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 170407)
To do this, I am adding a new language by right clicking on System/Languages -> Insert -> Language.

While I am able to do this for some languages, it does not add languages for some.

For e.g:
en-BE, en-CH, en-DE are created successfully

But
en-IT, en-NO, en-LU are not created

What am I missing here? Is there a config entry or setting I need to modify?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depend on the Cultures support on your system, The Windows Language Code Identifier.
See the Microsoft documentation about [MS-LCID].
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233965.aspx

Today a lot of cultures are supported, but there is a old tool (not sure if it is useful today) to add unsupported cultures to Sitecore. [marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Custom_Language_Registration](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Custom_Language_Registration.aspx)